# Input image dtype is bool. Interpolation is not defined with bool data type

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, scikit-image

I am facing this issue while using [Mask_RCNN](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN) to train on my custom dataset with multiple classes.

This error occurs when I start training. This is what I get:

`/home/parth/anaconda3/envs/compVision/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skimage/transform/_warps.py:830: FutureWarning: Input image dtype is bool. Interpolation is not defined with bool data type. Please set order to 0 or explicitely cast input image to another data type. Starting from version 0.19 a ValueError will be raised instead of this warning.
  order = _validate_interpolation_order(image.dtype, order)`

I keep getting this for like a hundred times and then the kernel dies.
Please Help!!

Comment: On a conceptual level, how would *you* want interpolation for boolean data to work?

Comment: TL;DR - In Mask RCNN library, they are passing order=1, due to which this problem is popping up.<hr>Refer this issue. I have explained why it's happening. https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/6286

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Maybe you can try the skimage version 0.16.2。when I use the version 0.17.2， I faced the same issue.Good luck!Idont know why.

Comment: thnks! this works for me

Comment: Yeah ... which runs so well on Apple Silicon (not!)

Comment: It fixed my problem, I love you.

Comment: @trueToastedCode I installed it through conda, and it runs pretty fine on Apple Silicon. `conda install scikit-image=0.16.2`

Answer (score 9):

pip install -U scikit-image==0.16.2

Answer (score 6):

I also had the same issue while training the MaskRCNN model with two classes. Then uninstalled existing (mine was 0.19.2) scikit-image by the command:

**pip uninstall scikit-image**

and installed 0.16.2 version of the same package by the command:

**pip install scikit-image==0.16.2**

Note: tensorflow and keras version used are:

tensorflow==2.2.0
keras==2.3.1

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming you are trying to transform a mask (i.e. in Mask_RCNN). If that is the case, one solution is to do as asked (explicitly cast the type to something else) and then convert it back into a boolean mask.

Changing the scikit-image version is really just a bandaid that eventually won't work as other packages need to be updated that are incompatible with the old scikit-image version.

I have provided an example solution below that I have verified to work well:

```
# resize the mask cast as uint32 then convert back to bool
    img_resized = skimage.util.img_as_bool(skimage.transform.resize(
        image.astype(np.uint32), output_shape,
        order=order, mode=mode, cval=cval, clip=clip,
        preserve_range=preserve_range, anti_aliasing=anti_aliasing,
        anti_aliasing_sigma=anti_aliasing_sigma))
    return img_resized
```

Hope that helps. Seems like this is a common question, and downgrading scikit-image is not an ideal solution.

Comment: I couldn't downgrade to and older scikit-image because of C issues and then this finally resolved my issue. For the ones interested I had to change the resize function at the bottom of utils.py because that wasn't clear from the post